# I have a problem when I fix my code in the first java maven project

Tags: java, maven

I'm tired of trying to fix this:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 ): The operation was cancelled.
```

I need help from everyone

Comment: That version of xstream [doesn't seem to exist on Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream). Use a newer version of xstream (e.g. latest is 1.4.19). I would also question why your "new" Maven project is even trying to rely on such an old version of a library. If you need a better answer, then you need to provide a [mre] in your question, including your pom.xml.

Comment: The [version exist](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.3.1/jar) but the problem is related to network/firewall/proxy issue...